# Mesos kills mpiexec, without any chance to run any useful job

Tags: python, apache, mpi, mesos

colleagues!
I was writing own framework for Apache Mesos 0.22.1 in pure Python ( using their API ), because we have very specific requirements, which are not handled by another frameworks ( such as Marathon, for example ).

We are going to start some MPI jobs from Mesos ( they all are written in Python too ( using mpi4py ))

But I was stopped at very beginning, because it seems, that Mesos master kills mpiexec just after its start. mpiexec only writes 'killing all jobs...' and then dies.

Here is We are going to start some MPI jobs from Mesos ( they all are written in Python too ( using mpi4py ))

Take a look at the code of my framework ( its pretty basic, and have much more in common with this : https://github.com/apache/mesos/tree/master/mpi ):

```
  if cpus < CPUS or mem < MEM:
    print "Declining offer due to too few resources"
    driver.declineOffer(offer.id)
  else:
    tid = self.mpdsLaunched
    self.mpdsLaunched += 1

    print "Accepting offer on %s to start mpd %d" % (offer.hostname, tid)

    task = mesos_pb2.TaskInfo()
    task.task_id.value = str(tid)
    task.slave_id.value = offer.slave_id.value
    task.name = "task %d " % tid

    cpus = task.resources.add()
    cpus.name = "cpus"
    cpus.type = mesos_pb2.Value.SCALAR
    cpus.scalar.value = CPUS

    mem = task.resources.add()
    mem.name = "mem"
    mem.type = mesos_pb2.Value.SCALAR
    mem.scalar.value = MEM

    uri = task.command.uris.add()
    uri.value= parser_config.get_option("PATH_TO_DEPLOY_SCRIPT")

    task.command.value = "mpiexec -n 3 test_mpi.py -u" 
    tasks.append(task)
    print "Replying to offer: launching mpd %d on host %s" % (tid, offer.hostname)
    driver.launchTasks(offer.id, tasks)
```

You see, I'm trying to start mpiexec from Mesos directly, and this gives no result. 
By the way, in order to fight the problem, I had tried:

```
    1. To launch some bash script from Mesos, which will then start mpiexec ( no result )
    2. To start 
       nohup mpiexec -n 3 test_mpi.py -u &
    3. To put some delays after mpiexec run:
       mpiexec -n 3 test_mpi.py -u && sleep 30 && echo "Yeah!"
```

But in all these cases the result is identical : mpiexec is killed by mesos master with insane persistence.

Maybe someone had a similar problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Wow! :-)
Guys, no one will believe it, but when I changed mpiexec to mpirun, everything works fine!
I.e. now my string is like that:

```
mpiexec -n 3 test_mpi.py -u &
```

I'm curious -- what is difference, after all?